# Bijection between $[\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}]$ and $[\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \{0,1\}]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ZFC (edit : and other axiomatic systems), does there exists a bijection between $[\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}]$ and $[\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \{0,1\}]$?

Extrapolating from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form it seems that there is exactly $2^{2^n}$ functions from a set where elements are described with n bits to $\{0,1\}$

So by imagining what the limit would be for all possible integer size, it seems that an infinite string of $\{0,1\}$ is exactly the description of one particular function from N to $\{0,1\}$

But then with the same argument, an infinite string of $\{0,1\}$ would also be the description of exactly one particular function from a subset of $\mathbb N$ (which also happens to be a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$ in that view expressed here) to $\{0,1\}$

Hence i would tend to conclude that $[\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}]$ and $[\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \to \{0,1\}]$ are the same thing ..

What is the view of ZFC (and other axiomatic systems) on the matter, do both set of functions have the same cardinality (which i take is equivalent to ask for the existence of a bijection between the two ) ?

Edit : i would like to extend the questions to other axiomatic systems than ZFC

Comment: Your writing is a little ambiguous.  "All subsets of X" is often represented by $ \mathcal{P}(X) $ (As its the power set).  Is your second statement $ [ \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}) ] $ or $ [ \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N}) \to \{0,1\} ] $.  Either way there is no bijections between these sets.  I'll give an answer once you clarify this.

Comment: [All subset of N] would be P(N) yes.

Answer (score 2):

No, there can't be.  Your first set is isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, whereas your second set, being $2^{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})}$, is isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$.  But by the 'generalized' Cantor theorem that $A\not\approx \mathcal{P}(A)$ for any set $A$, these two sets can't be isomorphic to each other - just take $A=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.  Choice doesn't play a role here at all - Cantor's theorem is a theorem of ZF, and I don't know of any axiomatic systems (including intuitionist or constructive ones) where the core argument of the proof doesn't go through.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit the isomorphism between $2^{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$. ?

Comment: Wouldn't an axiomatic system that force $[\mathcal P(\mathbb N)]$ to only be computable infinite strings of {0,1} makes it indeed injective into N ? Are you saying that no such axiomatic system exsists as far as you are aware ?

Comment: @user3286435 If you work in a system where all relations etc. must be computable, then you're right that $\mathcal{P}_c(\mathbb{N})$ is countable in the 'base model' - that is externally - but there's no _computable_ bijection between $\mathcal{P}_c(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{N}$ - that is, $\mathcal{P}_c(\mathbb{N})$ is 'internally' uncountable.

Comment: How does that automatically make the associatated function spaces automatically impossible to build a bijection onto ?